# How do you bind multiple concrete implementations to one abstract class

Tags: php, laravel

I had one MessagingService interface and one concrete implementation, LiveMessagingService, and I bound it in the register() method of a service provider. This worked fine.

```
$this->app->bind(
    'App\Services\Messaging\MessagingService',    
    'App\Services\Messaging\LiveMessagingService'
);
```

However, I now want to version my service and controllers and provide 2 concrete implementations. I've attempted it by doing this:

```
    // v4
    $this->app->when(\App\Http\Controllers\Api\v4\MessagesController::class)
        ->needs(MessagingService::class)
        ->give(function($app) {
            return $app->make(\App\Services\Messaging\LiveMessagingService::class);
        });

    // v5
    $this->app->when([App\Http\Controllers\Api\v5\MessagesController::class])
        ->needs(MessagingService::class)
        ->give(function(Application $app) {
            return $app->make(\App\Services\Messaging\v5\LiveMessagingService::class);
        });
```

However, on executing the code it's throwing this error:

```
[2024-01-23 17:54:13 +0800] local.ERROR: Target [App\Services\Messaging\MessagingService] is not instantiable. (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target [App\\Services\\Messaging\\MessagingService] is not instantiable. at /API/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1090)"} []
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible with the IOC container in Laravel?

Comment: I am curious to know if your two versioned services are not similar enough to use it in different controllers, why it does share the same interface?

Comment: @hassan It's a versioned API for an app. I want existing users to continue to hit v4 endpoint, but then I'll push out a release with a v5 endpoint to users who have updated the app. The service api is identical but it returns updated json for the new version. I could simply create a separate method for v5... but I like to try to be clever and exploit polymorphism. 

Comment: I see, however, how do you call your Services?

Comment: The interface is injected into the controller handler function, i.e. MessagingService. Then I just call a method on the service. Depending on whether I use v4 or v5 controller, I want it to cal the correct implementation. Ya get me?

Comment: did you alias `MessagingService` correctly in that file? also the second contextual binding isn't using a reference to the root namespace for the `when` so that isn't the class you think it is

Comment: @lagbox I already fixed the namespace issue, still not joy. I didn't use any alias. Is that necessary?

Comment: yea, otherwise it would think that class reference is relative to the current namespace of the file you are in

Comment: Oh I get ya, I'm from languages where they call it 'import' . Yes, I'd added the 'use' alias for MessagingService at the top of the file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that I'm currently using. Potentially it's better than the when/needs/give setup in my question, as I don't have to modify the 'when' clause when I introduce new classes further down the line.

This is in my ServiceProvider class

```
public function register()
{
    $path = $this->app->request->getRequestUri();
    if(str_starts_with($path, "/api/v5")) {
        $this->app->bind(
            'App\Services\Messaging\MessagingService',
            'App\Services\Messaging\v5\LiveMessagingService'
        );
    } else {
        $this->app->bind(
            'App\Services\Messaging\MessagingService',
            'App\Services\Messaging\v4\LiveMessagingService'
        );
    }
}
```